# TextWatcher - CharSequence S isn't updated

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have an edittext and a textwatcher attached to it. I'd like as soon as user presses '1', "Hello" to be written instead (so "11" gives "HelloHello"). I use:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.length() > 0  && s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1) == '1' )
    {
        String current_string = s.toString().substring(0,(s.length() - 1));
        et.setText(current_string + "Hello");
        length = s.length();
        et.setSelection(length);
        System.out.println(s.toString()); //←←←←←←←←←←
    }
```

Everything is running fine. But except one thing I am curious about. When I start app and enter "1" it is converted to "Hello". And the println function prints "1". Shouldn't it print "Hello" instead? Why isn't charsequence s being updated just after the setText function? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `onTextChanged` method you are not changing the value of `s`, thats why it prints "1". When you call `et.setText`, the method `onTextChanged` will be called again and this time the value of `s` will be "Hello". Everything is working correctly here.